# Android - initial clicking tutorial

Tags: java, android, layout

How to implement such a functionality in an Android application which presents to the user initial clicking tutorial (while running application for the first time)? It should look similar to how it is used in that application:
[image: Initial clicking tutorial sample]

I've searched through forums, but did not find the answer.
I've already seen such a functionality in many other apps and its purpose is to show to the users the functionalities of the most important buttons/layout elements in the main activity of our application.
How to implement such a functionality? And how to indicate that user already completed "clicking tutorial" so it will not show for the next time?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you may try to add your demo layout into android.R.id.content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at this library here [ShowcaseView](https://github.com/amlcurran/ShowcaseView) or here [RoboDemo](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/RoboDemo).

(I think "ShowcaseView" library is the one you're looking for)

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thank you! I've managed with ShowcaseView. It's quite inconvenient in terms of configuration (e.g. styles, fonts, colors etc.), but that is what I was looking for :).

Answer (score -1):

[TutorialView](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1408) might fit your requirements.